# set package version as env var in Nx

Tags: environment-variables, package.json, nxjs

I am trying to access from browser the package.json version

In Nx, it is possible to hardcode env vars in a .env file and have them passed to `process.env.{varname}` if the variables are prefixed vith `NX_`.
I can't hardcode the variable though, I need to read it from package.json.

Anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Nx workspace, the custom webpack configuration file can be named according to your preference, as you will reference it explicitly in the `angular.json` or `workspace.json` file. A common convention for naming this file is `webpack.config.js` or `custom-webpack.config.js`.
See "[Configure webpack on your Nx workspace](https://nx.dev/packages/webpack/documents/webpack-config-setup)"

In your webpack configuration file, you can import the `package.json`:

```js
const packageJson = require('./package.json');
const version = packageJson.version;
```

Use the `DefinePlugin` in your webpack configuration to define the variable based on `version`.
See "[Using environment variables in Angular applications](https://nx.dev/recipes/angular/use-environment-variables-in-angular)".
In your custom webpack configuration, it might look like this:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = (config) => {
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NX_PACKAGE_VERSION': JSON.stringify(version)
    })
  );
  return config;
};
```

Update your application's build options to use the custom webpack configuration. For example, if you are using Angular, you can update the `angular.json` file:

```json
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
    "options": {
      "customWebpackConfig": {
        "path": "./custom-webpack.config.js"
      },
    }
  }
}
```

You should now be able to access the version in your code like this:

```js
console.log(process.env.NX_PACKAGE_VERSION);
```

Comment: thank you @VonC, I did try that but it got completely ignored. I found that nx already injects some plugins, amongst which the DefinePlugin. So I just grabbed that and added my var to the definitions. Why pushing a new DefinPlugin had no effect I had no idea

Comment: I am still going to accept your answer becuase it's a good answer that would be useful to most people with a similar issue

Comment: @undefinederror It is possible that the way Nx is handling the webpack configuration, particularly with the DefinePlugin, is causing your custom addition to be ignored or overridden. By modifying the existing DefinePlugin instance directly, you make sure that your custom definition is incorporated into the existing plugin configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by @Vonc should work in most cases. However it did not for me.
I see that nx already defines some plugins, and maybe that's why pushing a second DefinePlugin did not work (not sure).
So instead of adding another one I grab the existing one and amend the definitions.
No need to import package.json, the version is exposed in `$npm_package_version`

`project.json`

```json
"targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nx/webpack:webpack",
      "options": {
        "compiler": "babel",
        "webpackConfig": "path-to/webpack.config.js",
      },
```

`webpack.config.js`

```js
const { composePlugins, withNx } = require('@nx/webpack');
const { withReact } = require('@nx/react');

// Nx plugins for webpack.
module.exports = composePlugins(withNx(), withReact(), (config, { options, context }) => {
  const definePlugin = config.plugins.find((x) => x.constructor.name === 'DefinePlugin');

  if (definePlugin) {
    definePlugin.definitions['process.env'] = {
      ...(definePlugin.definitions['process.env'] || {}),
      NX_PKG_VERSION: JSON.stringify(process.env.npm_package_version),
    };
  }

  return config;
});
```

Comment: Nicely done. Upvoted. That will iterate through the existing plugins, finds the `DefinePlugin`, and then amend the definitions with the `NX_PKG_VERSION` key, pulling the value from `process.env.npm_package_version`.